# sort asc desc php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some code for ascending and descending sort, when click on link, table will be sorted asc and after another they will be sort desc. Generally code is working but they don't return first and last field from database. When sort desc don't return last and when asc then don't return first field. I will come piece of code here. Somebody to help ? Thanks.

this is the link for request

```
echo "<th>ID 
        <a href='sort_user.php?sortItemsId&order=" . (isset($_GET['order'])?!$_GET['order']: 1) . "'>
            <i class='fa fa-sort' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </a>
        </th>";

if (isset($_REQUEST["sortItemsId"])) {
            $isAsc = isset($_GET['order'])? (bool) !$_GET['order']: 1;
            $sql = "SELECT id, name, number, email, recovery_email, address       FROM users ORDER BY id " .($isAsc?"ASC":"DESC").";";
            $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

.....
}
```

Comment: SQL Looks fine. I think you Problem is in the code which print out the data.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get row from database? Maybe it's something wrong with your loop while showing the results somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have nested while loops in your code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    //some code
    //$row is first object
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
        //printing data
        //$row is replaced by second object and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post now full code with printing data. I got result but don't get last field when sorting desc and don't get first field when sorting asc

```
       if (isset($_REQUEST["sortItemsId"])) {
         $isAsc = isset($_GET['order'])? (bool) !$_GET['order']: 1;
         $sql = "SELECT id, CRMContact, CRMOrganization, username, recovery_email, status FROM tb_users ORDER BY id " .($isAsc?"ASC":"DESC").";";
         $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
                echo "<div class='container'><table class='table table-striped'><thead>";
                echo " <tr><th>ID 
                <a href='existing_user.php?sortItemsId&order=" . (isset($_GET['order'])?!$_GET['order']: 1) . "'>
                    <i class='fa fa-sort' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                </a>
                </th> <th>CRM Contact</th><th>CRM Organization</th>";
                echo "<th>Username</th><th>Recovery email</th><th>Status</th><th>Actions</th></tr></thead>";
                $i = 0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {  
                $i++; 
                $id = $row->id;         
                echo "<tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>$row->id</td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>$row->CRMContact</td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>$row->CRMOrganization</td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'><a href='edit_user.php?idEdit=$row->id'>$row->username</a></td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>$row->recovery_email</td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>$row->status</td>
                            <td style='background-color:" . (($i % 2 == 0) ? '#fff' : '#f9f9f9') . "'>
                                <div class='btn-group'>
                                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false' style='background-color: #4076BC; color: #fff;'>
                                  <i class='fa fa-fire' aria-hidden='true'></i>

                                    Action <span class='caret'></span>
                                  </button>
                                  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                    <li><a href='view_user.php?viewId=$row->id'>View</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=''>Edit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='existing_user.php?deleteUser=$row->id'>Delete</a></li>";
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                    if ($row->deactivated == 1) {
                                        echo "<li><a href='existing_user.php?deactivateUserAcc=activate&id=$id'>Activate</a></li>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<li><a href='existing_user.php?deactivateUserAcc=deactivate&id=$id'>Deactivate</a></li>";
                                    }
                                  "</ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>";
                }
                echo "</table></div>";
            } 
        } else if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Database is empty.');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong.');</script>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have nested while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)). The nested loop is overriding existing $row.

Comment: You should remove the first or second while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) loop, as @ElChupacabra says, is overriding the existing row